# Update OpenQuery with parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, openquery

#### UPDATE OPENQUERY Help

> I am trying to update an Oracle 11 table via a linked server in SQL, now the linked server and select statements all appear correct and I think I am very close to cracking this, but I am having issues with the update.  The other OPENQUERY commands work correctly e.g.

*`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT PL.place_id, PL.phy_svc_grp_b FROM OU_DBA.REQUEST RT INNER JOIN OU_DBA.PLACE PL ON RT.place_id = PL.place_id WHERE (RT.phy_svc_grp_b IS NULL) AND        (PL.phy_svc_grp_b IS NOT NULL)')`*

This is performing as expected; this information is then placed into a temporary table and using a `WHILE` I create an update openquery;

```
SET @TEMP_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MissingRegions)
            WHILE @TEMP_INDEX < @TEMP_COUNT +1
                BEGIN
                -----Clear out the SQL String
                SET @SQL_STRING = ''

                -----Assign the Place ID.
                SET @PLACE_ID = (SELECT PLACE_ID FROM #MissingRegions WHERE ID =@TEMP_INDEX)

                -----Assign the Region.
                SET @REGION = (SELECT GROUP_B FROM #MissingRegions WHERE ID =@TEMP_INDEX)

                SET     @SQL_STRING ='UPDATE OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, ''SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID =''' + @PLACE_ID + ''')' + ' SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = ''' + @REGION + ''''
                PRINT   @SQL_STRING
                EXEC        (@SQL_STRING)

            ----Increment the index value by 1
                SET @TEMP_INDEX = @TEMP_INDEX +1
        END
```

The output from the Print command returns the following;

`UPDATE OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID ='ES5159') SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = '1000'`

But I keep getting the following error for each record i try to update;
*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'ES5159'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.*

If anyone could possibly suggest where I may be going wrong and provide a solution for this I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Looks like you're just missing a quote at the end after '1000' so that your whole SELECT statement is quoted.  Change REGION + '''' to REGION + ''''''

Comment: Thanks Mark, I added the extra ' but I now get "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'ES4658'." for example when trying to execute the following openquery command - UPDATE OPENQUERY(M3Live_Link, 'SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID ='ES4658') SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = '2000''.  Grrr! I know I must be missing something obvious but cannot see what it is.

Comment: You need another ' so that it looks like 'ES4658''). Also, the end should look like '2000', not '2000".

Comment: Confused Mark, you said : Also, the end should look like '2000', not '2000", but earlier said Looks like you're just missing a quote at the end after '1000', which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been single quote, not quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need your output to look like this:

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID =''ES5159''') SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = '1000'
```

To do this, SET your string like this:

```
SET     @SQL_STRING ='UPDATE OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, ''SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID =''''' + @PLACE_ID + ''''''')' + ' SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = ''' + @REGION + ''''
```

Comment: Mark, I tried your suggestion `SET @SQL_STRING ='UPDATE OPENQUERY(M3Live_Link, ''SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID =''' + @PLACE_ID + ''''')' + ' SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = ''' + @REGION + ''''` but still no joy, using print I am trying to execute the following code `UPDATE OPENQUERY(M3Live_Link, 'SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID ='ES1207'') SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = '1000'` but get the message `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'ES1207'.`  If you can also let me know how to add carriage return in comments that would be great.

Comment: Edited.  Please try now.  There's an extra ': 'ES1207''

Comment: Copied your sample from above and I still get an error - sorry.  Using your code above i get `UPDATE OPENQUERY(M3Live_Link, 'SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID ='1502398') SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = '2000''`  And this returns the error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '1502398'.`.  I also tried the extra quote as mentioned in your above edit, `UPDATE OPENQUERY(M3Live_Link, 'SELECT PHY_SVC_GRP_B FROM [OU_DBA].[REQUEST] WHERE PLACE_ID ='ES1657'') SET PHY_SVC_GRP_B = '1000''` and this also errored.

Comment: @GordonBarclay: Edited again and tested on a SQL Server instance.  This should do it.  Be mindful of the single quotes around 'ES5159'.  That's the tricky bit.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and then received an Oracle error, removed the [ ] brackets from schema and table name and all seems fine now.  Many thanks for your help, I think tried variations of this but not double quotes at the beginning of the ES5159.